# How does SystemJS use the configuration under "packages"?

Tags: angular, systemjs

In `systemjs.config.js`, we have the `packages` objects which provides configurations for *paths* in our application.

For example, here we tell `SystemJS` that the default extension for the path `node_modules/moment` is `js`:

```
packages: {
  'node_modules/moment': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

My question is - when does `SystemJS` uses this configuration? When does it actually load the file?